# Git-Tower for Mac - how can i use --no-verify flag in each commit?

Tags: git-tower

We are using husky pre-commit hooks and i cannot commit with tower ever since. I use the CLI for my commits now but i want to be able to use [Git Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac) as well.

Any users out there know a quick fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable hooks introduced by `husky` in frontend project, you can:

Create `environment.plist` file in `~/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower3/` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

That's it. Next time if you try to push something, hooks introduced by `husky` will be disabled.

Note: you can also use this flag with CLI like this:
`HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1 git <command> ...`

I've also wrote a [blog post](https://qacenter.io/blog/skip-husky-hooks) about it.

Answer (score 5):

In general, Desktop Apps don't have the Shell environment available. 
In order to enable you to use your commit hook with the bundled Git binary, you'll need to set up an environment.plist file manually.

Here is a detailed guide for this in the Tower Help guide: https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/faq-and-tips/faq/hook-scripts

Please feel free to reach out to us via https://www.git-tower.com/support/contact if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this useful article: https://dev.to/studiospindle/using-husky-s-pre-commit-hook-with-a-gui-21ch

You can create a file `~/.huskyrc` containing:

```sh
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

or if you use nvm:

```sh
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling husky you can also make it work with Tower. It took me a while to figure this out. In MacOS Tower (and other GUI apps) does not run in the same environment as your cli does, in my case zsh.

I added the following to the `~/.huskyrc` file to make this work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1317